# incomplete shadow with THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am a beginner with javascript and THREE.js and I need help.

You can see below what I obtained
[image: this what I obtained]

and this is the code:

```js
// on initialise le moteur de rendu
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    
    // on initialise la scène
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
    // on initialise la camera que l’on place ensuite sur la scène
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100000 );
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 1000);
    scene.add(camera);
    
    // plane
 me = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(900,550), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xffffff}));
 scene.add( me );
    
    me.position.x = 130;
    me.position.y = 10;
    me.rotation.y = -20;
    
    // on créé un  cube au quel on définie un matériau puis on l’ajoute à la scène 
    cube = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry( 100, 100, 100 ), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:0x00ffff}) );
    scene.add( cube );
    
    cube.position.y = 0;
    cube.position.x = 20;
    cube.position.z = 0;
    cube.rotation.y = 0;
    
    scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x212223) );
      
    light = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 1);
    light.position.set(-300,-100,20); 
    light.angle = Math.PI/5;
    light.shadowCameraVisible = true;
    scene.add(light);
    
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMapDarkness = 1;
    
     light.castShadow = true;
     light.intensity = 0.8;
     cube.castShadow = true;
     cube.receiveShadow = true;
     me.receiveShadow = true;
    
     lightHelper = new THREE.SpotLightHelper( light );
    scene.add(lightHelper);
    
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

the rest of my code change the x and y value of the light or of the cube and the shadow of the cube is not always complete and I don't understand why... 
Like I am am beginner I think I have do a mistake in my code.

Comment: I tried your code on my machine and it worked : the shadow is complete.
Try updating everything.

Comment: yes its work when I put the position.x = 300 but it's don't work with all the x values and I don't understand why ( the rest of my animation modify the x value)

Answer (score 0):

> yes its work when I put the position.x = 300 but it's don't work with all the x values and I don't understand why ( the rest of my animation modify the x value)

Shadow mapping (usually) work like this:

You create a new orthographic or perspective camera (depending on if you use a directional or a point light), render the scene's z-buffer onto a texture, then when you render objects, you check if the point on the z-buffer, which corresponds to the current fragment has a higher z value, than the current fragment, and if it does, then it's in the shadow. if it has the exact same value (+- some amount because of the precision of the depth buffer), then it's in the light.

Because you need a camera to render the stuff on the screen, it has a minimal distance it can render something.

Tl;dr the clipping distance is your bane this time.

Comment: thank you and when I change the y value why the shadow is not always complete like in my picture ?

Comment: @sami54 Again, clipping issues

Comment: so... what can I do ? because in the animation I want do, the user can change the x value of the cube and the y value of the light (it's a animation for student about shadows)